# Scrollable area has a width limit?

Tags: winforms, scroll

I have a form with a Panel which covers the entire form and serves as a scrollable area for the child controls. Basically I put `PictureBox` controls into the panel, 3-4 in a column. The problem is when the number of `PictureBoxe` is high, I cannot place them all into the Panel, it just refuses to set `PictureBox.Left` property when I set it higher than about 32470 px, i.e. when I set it to 32570 it is being set down to 32470.

Is there a limit on the width of the scrollable parent then?

The code I use looks like this:

```
for (int a...)
{
    PictureBox pic = new PictureBox
    {
        Parent = panel1,
        Width = 150,
        Height = 150,
        Left = x,
        Top = y
    };
}
```

- `x` and `y` are calculated inside the loop to put the PictureBoxes in rows/columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am surprised that this is happening at that value. This is a limitation of Windows itself. It puts all of its messages in a 16 bit WORD, so the maximum value for any X or Y position should be 32767. You could always try to add another panel whenever this max is hit, and then you would be referencing from 0 in the new panel again?

Comment: Probably the width is less in my case because the image width is 150 px + spacing between the images. Anyway I didn't know there was such a limit and had to implement paging.